# How to highlight certain text in XTEXT runtime instance

Tags: syntax-highlighting, xtext

I have tried xtext highlighting code shared by Christian Dietrich here:  https://www.eclipse.org/forums/index.php/t/1096951/

However, its not working. I don't get any error but I don't see any highlight in runtime instance.

I have shared by project on Github: https://github.com/MisbahAwan/Merger

Please see and guide.

Comment: why do you have `MergerDslUiModule.java`and `MergerDslUiModule.xtend` you should add binding to the module class that was generated by the workflow.

Comment: Yeah, it worked. Thanks. Now I want to change color of text based on a condition in formatter2. Is it possible? How can I call it in formatter2? Please guide

Comment: Please note that I dont need to change color of keywords ... rather I want to change color of text. For example: Person: John ...... here "Person:" is a keyword but I want to change color of "John" (based on some condition i.e. if John appears more than once)

Comment: color and formatter have nothing todo with each other. SemanticHighlightingCalculator calcs styleids for positions, HighlightingConfiguration defines the style. so traverse the ast in SemanticHighlightingCalculator and give the positions. `NodeModelUtils`might help.

Comment: Hi. Now I want to do the same in xtext web ACE. Please guide how to?

Comment: according https://www.eclipse.org/Xtext/documentation/330_web_support.html ace does not support semantic highlighting